# I need a sanity check to compute the limit of a function in two variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, optimization

So I have $g(x,y) = \tfrac{f(x,y) - y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$, where $f(x,y) = \tfrac{y^3 -x^8y}{x^6 + y^2}$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$.

I want to find $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} g(x,y)$ if it exists.

My question is if after doing some algebraic manipulation, I can get g as a product of $\tfrac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$ and $\tfrac{x^6(1+x^2)}{x^6 + y^2}$, can I bound the former by $1$ in absolute value? What can I do with the second part of the product? I feel that the numerator would dominate but want to be rigorous with it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\left\lvert\frac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right\rvert\leq\frac {|y|}{\sqrt{y^2}}=1$

Comment: The problem is that bounding one factor by $1$ is only useful if the other factor goes to $0$, and that isn't true in this case.  As $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ along the curve $y=x^3$, we find that $\frac{x^6+x^8}{x^6+y^2}\to\frac12$

Comment: @saulspatz is the answer to go to polar co-ordinates as the denominator of g might suggest?

Comment: It might be, but I've been unable to make it work out that way.  A comment saying it works has been deleted, so I guess there was a mistake in that proof.  This seems to be a tough nut.

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks.  I didn't have time to follow up on your comment the other day, and when I say that it was gone today, I assumed you'd found an error.

Comment: @saulspatz posted an answer here yesterday

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, I saw it and upvoted it, thanks.  I was working along exactly the same lines, and I can't figure out where I went astray.  Unfortunately, I pitched my papers, so I can't refer to them.

Answer (score 1):

call the ratio $G,$  I got
$$ |G| = \frac{|y| x^6 (1+x^2)}{r (x^6 + y^2)}  $$
Demand $c = | \cos \theta | $  and $s = | \sin \theta | $

$$ |G| = \frac{r^7 c^6 s (1+r^2 c^2 )}{r^3 (r^4c^6 +s^2)}  $$
$$ |G| = \frac{r^4 c^6 s (1+r^2 c^2 )}{ r^4c^6 +s^2}  $$

We are allowed to demand $r < 1,$ so that $1+r^2 c^2 < 2,$
$$ |G| < 2 \frac{r^4 c^6 s }{ r^4c^6 +s^2}  $$

From $$ 0 \leq (r^2 c^3 \pm s)^2 $$
we get $$ r^4 c^6 + s^2 \geq 2 r^2 c^3 s   $$  and
$$ \frac{1}{r^4 c^6 + s^2} \leq \frac{1}{2 r^2 c^3 s}   $$

$$ |G| < 2 \frac{r^4 c^6 s }{ r^4c^6 +s^2} \leq 2 \frac{r^4 c^6 s }{2 r^2 c^3 s } \leq r^2 c^3 \leq r^2$$